# Pandas read_excel without excel being installed

Tags: python, excel, pandas

This may be a rather stupid question:

If I use the `pd.read_excel(somefile)` function in `python pandas` does this function require Excel to be installed on the machine executing the python code?

Comment: I thinks it's the file format rather than the application. Because the application is basically a means to read the file format and similarly is `read_excel`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short and sweet: No, it does not.

It [requires the `xlrd` Python package](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2e38d5552a5c7b2c0091cecddd483f4f08ad1d2c/pandas/io/excel.py#L550), which you can install in the same way you've installed `pandas` (e.g. `pip install xlrd`).

Comment: Great. Thanks for the swift reply. I do not understand how that works, however, as ".xls(x)" format is a "special" format linked to a proprietory program (unlike .txt file e.g.). So how does pandas know how to read this?

Comment: The spec for the format is well-known, so clever folks have written libraries to read and write files conforming to that format.

Comment: Understood. Thanks!